# Elder scrolls stuck in inventory

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 3 elder scrolls in my inventory that they won't let me remove. (Dragon,sun,blood). I finished dawn guard and defeated aldin which the scrolls are used for those quest lines. Why can't I remove them.

Comment: when you try to remove one it says they are quest items that can't be removed

Comment: Ya. It's being stupid

Comment: No just annoyed person that want his 60 extra slots back

Comment: @Jack How are you missing "60" slots from three scrolls?

Comment: @Nelson Each Elder Scroll has a weight of 20

Comment: Quest items, although has a "weight", are actually 0 weight until you can throw them away.  Try emptying everything else, and you'll see they actually weigh nothing.  [Source](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quest_Items)

Comment: U know I did that before and it equaled 0. I think I'm special

Answer (score 3):

You can sell the elder scrolls to the orc in the Arcanaeum in the College of Winterhold. The elder scrolls act similar to the items that you gather for Delvin Mallory in the Thieves guild and are part of hidden quests and usually result in you selling them to certain people. This can be seen on the wiki for Urag gro-shub [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Urag_gro-Shub).

Comment: Don't forget you can also sell them to Dexion: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dexion_Evicus